# Foreach datagridview row doesnt work

Tags: c#

I cant understand what this happen but my datagridview each ro loop doesnt work for all my rows.

I have also a checkbox cell which i need to get its value when is selected

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
            }

        }
```

It deletes some rows but not all selected

Comment: This is likely because you are modifying the collection inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing rows at the same time as iterating over them. That's always going to at least cause the *potential* for confusion - particularly as you're removing rows by index.

One option is to copy all the rows to a list first, and then also use `DataGridViewRowCollection.Remove(DataGridViewRow)` instead of removing by index:

```
// Take a copy first, to avoid complications when modifying the collection
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        // Remove the row rather than using the index
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```